# Where is the default save for animations?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I started to render an animation, and part way through it I changed the save location thinking that it was one big file and would save there after. Little did I know that its actually saving every frame, so now I'm missing the ones that were in the default folder. Is there a specific place I can go to get these files or are they gone?

Comment: Fire up a new Blender instance on it's own, take a look at it's output folder.  That's possibly where your previously rendered frames/files are.  If you're wanting just a single file containing all frames, try the H264 AVI format in the output tab.  Have a peek in the "Encoding" tab as well.  Make sure they're set to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the missing frames by starting a new instance of blender (has to be new project) and looking at the default save location. 
For me, the default save file was C:/tmp/